# Is there a way to create an arel_table from a query?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, arel

I have two tables (A and B) and a relatively complicated Active::Record::Relation that selects from a join of these two tables. The query executes correctly with `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query joined.to_sql`, that is, it prints out the columns I want from each table (A.id, A.title, b.num).

I would like to then pass this "joined" table as an Arel::Table, to be used in the rest of the program. However, when I run `at_j=joined.arel_table`, the Arel table is created from the original database A, not from the one resulting from the "joined" query, i.e. I get all the columns from A (not only the selected ones), and none of the columns from B.

I realise that a first step would be to create an arel table from an already filtered table, i.e. if A has columns id, title, c1, c2, c3... I would like to be able to do:

```
filtered=A.select(:id,:title)
at_f=filtered.arel_table
```

and only get id and title in at_f, but that is not what happens, I also get c1, c2, c3....

I know I could do

```
at_f=A.arel_table.project(:id,:title)
```

but this outputs an Arel::SelectManager, and I need to pass an Arel::Table (that is out of my hands).

I also would rather not build the query in Arel, because I need to modify the table A that was given as an input, and I can do that using `_selct!` and `joins!`.

Is there a way to achieve this? I thought of using something like

```
at_f=Arel::Table.new(filtered.to_sql)
```

but that fails, unsurprisingly...

Thanks in advance for your help.

................................

In case this is useful, this is how I get the "joined" active record relation:

```
A._select!(:id,:title,'b.num')
bf=B.where(c1: 'x',c2: 'y')
num=bf.select('id_2 AS A_id, COUNT(id_2) AS num').group(:id_2)
A.joins!("LEFT OUTER JOIN (#{num.to_sql}) b ON A.id = b.A_id")
```

and this is the query it generates:

```
# A.to_sql:
SELECT `A`.`id`, `A`.`title`, `b`.`num` 
  FROM `A` LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT id_2 AS A_id, COUNT(id_2) AS num 
      FROM `B` WHERE `B`.`c1` = 'x' AND `B`.`c2` = 'y' 
      GROUP BY `B`.`id_2`) b 
    ON A.id = b.A_id
```

Comment: I am more than happy to help (I love [tag:arel] questions) however I am bit unclear on the desired outcome here. What is the query you are trying to build and what objects are your expecting to be returned? Also you will need to explain this part *"I need to pass an Arel::Table (that is out of my hands)"* because you are not going to be able to get an `Arel::Table` out of this but we can get you very close and reasonably functionally equivalent if I understand the context.

Comment: Sorry I missed this... What I mean is that the piece of code I am writing is embedded in a much larger project, the Arel::Table gets passed around, and properties of the Arel::Table are being used in several functions that I am not allowed to change.
The use of this table (at the moment) only involves the columns inside the original table, and the contents are, for example, sorted with the elements of a given column. However, I am attempting to sort through the count on another table (num), but I am unable to pass this augmented table to the sorting function, as it only takes an Arel::Table.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I understand what you are trying for although I am not sure about the whole `Arel::Table` part but we can get you that AR Relation from `A` as follows:

```
  b_table = B.arel_table
  A.joins(
     Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin.new(b, b.create_on(
        b[:id_2].eq(A.arel_table[:id])
          .and(b[:c1].eq('x'))
          .and(b[:c2].eq('y'))
     )))
   .select(:id, :title, b[:id_2].count.as('num'))
   .group(:id,:title)
```

This will result in an ActiveRecord::Relation object and when executed will return `A` objects with only the following attributes: `id`, `title`, and `num`.

The SQL will be:

```
SELECT 
  a.id, 
  a.title,
  COUNT(b.id_2) AS num
FROM 
  a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON b.id_2 = a.id
    AND b.c1 = 'x'
    AND b.c2 = 'y'
GROUP BY 
  a.id,
  a.title
```

Which is equivalent to what you have now.

If you truly want to build the query you have now we can certainly do that without issue but this is a bit cleaner.

If this is not your intended outcome please clarify and I will update accordingly.

**Notes**:

1. I would like to make it clear that at no time will you be able to *"...pass an Arel::Table..."* that also contains query syntactics as that is not what a `Arel::Table` is.
2. We can produce an `Arel::Nodes::TableAlias` which kind of duck types an `Arel::Table` for most intents and purposes and will allow for a query (subquery).
3. It may be helpful to you to know that you can convert an AR query to Arel by simply using the `arel` method. For Example:

```
arel_query = A.select(:id,:title).arel 
#=> #<Arel::SelectManager:0x00007fffd541dd90 ...> 
arel_query.to_sql
#=> "SELECT a.id, a.title FROM a"
```

**UPDATE** with Additional Information:

- You can create an `Arel::Table` out of nothing `t =Arel::Table.new('c')`
- You can use this as a point of reference for table and column constructs e.g. `t[:id]` will return an `Attribute` and will generate SQL of `c.id`
- `Arel::Table#project` - is the `SELECT` command and returns `SelectManager` (this object is the primary means of interaction with the AST and the table). `SelectManager` also has `project` to add to the current projections.
- You can use a `Table` or a `TableAlias` as a source for the `SelectManager` using `#from`

```
c = Arel::Nodes::TableAlias.new([our query from above], t.name) 
sm = Arel::SelectManager.new(c) 
# alternately sm =  Arel::SelectManager.new; sm.from(c)
sm.project(c[:id])
#=> "SELECT [c].[id] FROM (SELECT a.id, a.title, COUNT(b.id_2) AS num FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON b.id_2 = a.id AND b.c1 = 'x' AND b.c2 = 'y'  GROUP BY a.id, a.title) [c]
```

- You can use the `t` table we created above or the `b` table alias to add columns, sort, etc.

```
sm.project(b[:title],t[:num]).order(t[:num])
sm.to_sql 
#=> SELECT [c].[id], [c].[title], [c].[num] FROM (SELECT a.id, a.title, COUNT(b.id_2) AS num FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON b.id_2 = a.id AND b.c1 = 'x' AND b.c2 = 'y'  GROUP BY a.id, a.title) [c]  ORDER BY [c].[num]
```

- You can access the "froms" in the `SelectManager` using the `froms` method which will give you access to the `TableAlias` in this case which may be what you are looking for regarding the need for an `Arel::Table`

```
sm.froms[0]
#=> #<Arel::Nodes::TableAlias:0x00007fffbddc7160 ...>
```

Comment: Thanks for the cleaner query provided, that is useful, and I will adopt it. However, it does not solve my problem. The query I had (as ugly as it may be) worked. 

My current issue is on how to build an Arel::Table from that query, which if I understand correctly, you said is not possible... and makes it explicit I do not understand what an Arel::Table is... but I think that you might have provided a solution with the last bits of information.
I can convert my active record query to an arel select manager and then produce a table alias, which almost does the trick:
`query.arel.as('alias')`

Comment: However, the table alias does not completely behave like a table... for example, it does not have a `project` method defined... so a last piece of the puzzle (and maybe you'll again need to underline when I do not understand what an arel table is), would be to be able to get an Arel::Table::Alias into an Arel::Table

Comment: @FranciscoHerrerias-Azcue okay I am still not 100% sure what you are looking for so I will update the post with a bunch of information that you can use as you see fit.